# How do i clean up / minimize the storage usage of my container from building opencv in dockerfile

Tags: opencv, docker

Given my docker file

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-cudnn6-devel-ubuntu14.04
RUN apt-get update


# disable interactive functions
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive



#################Install MiniConda and other dependencies##########
ENV CONDA_DIR /opt/conda
ENV PATH $CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH
ENV OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS $(nproc)

RUN mkdir -p $CONDA_DIR && \
    echo export PATH=$CONDA_DIR/bin:'$PATH' > /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    git \
    g++ \
    graphviz \
    software-properties-common \
    python-software-properties \
    python3-dev \
    libhdf5-dev \
    libopenblas-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libblas-dev \
    libtbb2 \
    libtbb-dev && \
    apt-get -qq install -y \
    build-essential \ 
    unzip \
    cmake \
    pkg-config \
    libjpeg8-dev \
    libtiff4-dev \
    libjasper-dev \
    libpng12-dev \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libv4l-dev \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    gfortran && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    wget --quiet https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    /bin/bash /Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -f -b -p $CONDA_DIR && \
    rm Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh




#########################MPI###########################
RUN cd /tmp && \
        wget "https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v2.1/downloads/openmpi-2.1.1.tar.gz" && \
        tar xzf openmpi-2.1.1.tar.gz && \
        cd openmpi-2.1.1  && \
        ./configure --with-cuda && make -j"$(nproc)" install # && ldconfig



#######################NCCL###########################
ENV CPATH /usr/local/cuda/include:/usr/local/include:$CPATH
RUN cd /usr/local && git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/nccl.git && cd nccl && \
    sed -i '/NVCC_GENCODE ?=/a \                -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \\' Makefile && \
        make CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda -j"$(nproc)" && \
        make install && ldconfig

######### Compile for devices with cuda compute compatibility 3 (e.g. GRID K520 on aws) second line above
# UNCOMMENT line below to compile for GPUs with cuda compute compatibility 3.0
#        sed -i '/NVCC_GENCODE ?=/a \                -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \\' Makefile && \
##########




###################Setup User##########################
ENV NB_USER chainer
ENV NB_UID 1000

RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash -N -u $NB_UID $NB_USER -g sudo -p $(perl -e'print crypt("chainer", "aa")') && \
    mkdir -p $CONDA_DIR && \
    chown chainer $CONDA_DIR -R && \
    mkdir -p /src && \
    chown -R chainer /src
#    mkdir -p /opencv && \
#    chown -R chainer /opencv && \
#    mkdir -p /opencv_contrib && \
#    chown -R chainer /opencv_contrib





####################Python 3#########################
ARG python_version=3.5.2
RUN conda install -y python=${python_version} && \
     pip install -U pip && \
     conda install Pillow scikit-learn notebook pandas matplotlib mkl nose pyyaml six h5py && \
     pip install numpy  && \
     pip install chainer && \
     pip install chainercv && \
#     pip install opencv-python && \
     pip install pyyaml && \
     conda clean -yt

#    pip install -U pip && \
#
#    conda install Pillow scikit-learn notebook pandas matplotlib mkl nose pyyaml six h5py && \
#
#
#    pip install mpi4py && \
#    pip install cython && \
#
#    pip install chainer && \
#    pip install chainercv && \
#    pip install chainermn && \





ENV PYTHONPATH $CONDA_DIR/lib/python3.5/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH
ENV PYTHONPATH /src/:$PYTHONPATH

WORKDIR /src



##OPENCV##
RUN wget https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.3.0.zip -O opencv3.zip && \
    unzip -q opencv3.zip && mv /src/opencv-3.3.0 /opencv && \
    wget https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/archive/3.3.0.zip -O opencv_contrib3.zip && \
    unzip -q opencv_contrib3.zip && mv /src/opencv_contrib-3.3.0 /opencv_contrib
RUN rm -r -f /opencv/build && mkdir /opencv/build && \
    cd /opencv/build && \
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
        -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
        -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$CONDA_DIR \
    -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=$CONDA_DIR/lib/python3.5 \
    -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIRS=$CONDA_DIR/include/python3.5m \
    -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$CONDA_DIR/bin/python3 \
    -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$CONDA_DIR/lib/python3.5/site-packages \
        -D WITH_TBB=ON \
        -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opencv_contrib/modules \
        -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
        -D WITH_IPP=OFF \
        -D WITH_V4L=ON .. && \
    make -j"$(nproc)" && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig

######################################################




USER chainer
```

It ends up at whooping 15GB in size.

What can I do to reduce the size in terms of all the selfbuild stuff happening? can some be deleted again?

Comment: do you need the opencv extra modules? These are usually the experimental and non-free stuff. Also you're compiling cuda compute capability 3.0, is this supported on your hardware?

Comment: I am using a Tesla M60 cards (microsoft azure) and yes, i can remove the extra moduels ofcause

Comment: I'd remove the opencv extra modules, if using cuda you could set the cuda compute setting to `-gencode=arch=compute_50,code=sm_50` seeing as you have a maxwell card, this won't necessarily make the container smaller but the code could potentially be more efficient. Also what opencv modules are really using as you could remove a lot of them, plus sometimes it will build stuff like tests, docs, etc.. which are unnecessary, I'm talking about this from my experience of using CMAKE when compiling from the source, I don't know about docker but it maybe similar

Comment: docker is like the filesystem, if it takes up space normally, it also takes up space in docker